# Why isn’t my object collected by an autorelease pool?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I wrote an simple demo

```
@implementation A

- (void)a{
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.com"];
    return self;
}
@end

A *a = [A new];
while (YES) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
    [a a];  
}
```

but seems it will keep running and never crash.
so when will an autorelease object be releaed?

Comment: I expected the `url` will be released by `autorelease` pool and then the program goes to crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No run-loop processing is done while the thread sleeps, so that the main run loop never runs during your endless while-loop and autoreleased objects are not collected by the default pool. If you spin the run loop, your code should crash just fine:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
```

But it might be the case that the simple `NSLog` will work even though the object was released. [Enabling zombies](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) should do the trick for sure (provided that you spin the run loop).

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect to happen?

You only have one `NSURL` instance floating about.

The implementation details of `NSLog()` are just that; implementation details.  It is equally as likely that `NSLog()` creates its own autorelease pool as it is that `NSLog()` special cases `"%@"` such that it just logs the `description` of the passed object; nothing allocated in the pool.

How are you determining whether or not a crash should happen in the first place?  Given a 1/2 second pause, even if it were to allocate 128 bytes per pass, you'd be looking at -- what -- a few years, nearly a decade?, before it allocates 2GB of memory?

Comment: Sometimes an `autorelease` object will be released instantly, but in this demo it seems can't be released by `autorelease` pool.

Comment: An `autorelease` will *never* **never** cause the object to be released instantly.